# Getting Instagram's followers data using Curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to fetch the number of followers of an instagram account through web scraping and curl. Using their API may be easier but i want to know why this won't work, because in many case i got the data through HTML.

```
static $url='https://www.instagram.com/cats_of_instagram/';

function getUrlContent($url){
    try {
    $curl_connection = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Data are stored in $data
    $data = (curl_exec($curl_connection));
        $position = strpos($data,"<span data-reactid=\".0.1.0.0:0.1.3.1.0.2\"> followers</span>");
        print_r($position);


     curl_close($curl_connection);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Problem is the function `strpos` does not return position.

```
$position = strpos($data,"<span data-reactid=\".0.1.0.0:0.1.3.1.0.2\"> followers</span>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.

The element you're looking for is rendered by javascript, after the page has loaded.

`curl` doesn't wait for scripts to run (nor does it run any). It just returns the html.

You can easily verify this by printing `$data`. Or by looking at the page's source.

To "see" the element you're looking for, you need to use the DOM inspector.